# What is the best way (price wise) to travel from Japan to Mexico and Venezuela, then come back?

Tags: air-travel, japan, mexico, venezuela

What I want to do is go to those two countries for a week each. Basically the order doesn't matter much for me. But I must depart from Japan and come back.

I was wondering if there was someone experienced in this. For example I would think that Japan - Mexico - Venezuela is cheaper since I would go through the United States. But maybe I am wrong, maybe it depends on the season for each country?

Comment: What time of year? Where are you travelling from in Japan?  Where in those countries are you wanting to go to?

Comment: Hello Mark, I would like to travel next year between February and April. I am in Kyoto so I would be leaving from the Kansai Airport. In Mexico I will arrive at Mexico city. In Venezuela I want to go to a nice place near the ocean preferably near Maracaibo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do like to push them - once again, if you're really stuck and don't know where to look, consider [Flightfox](http://www.flightfox.com).  I'm not affiliated, although I do compete on there as one of their 'experts'.  Basically they have a bunch of 'experts' that compete to find you the best price.  With what may work best as an open-jawed flight or a double-return (Japan->Mexico return, Mexico->Venezuela return) will be investigated by people on there.

It's not a free service, but if you do want to use it, check out my profile on here for a discount link.

Alternatively sites like [kayak](http://www.kayak.com) and [skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.net) are a good start if you want to do all the grunt work yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried some of these sites but the price seems to vary greatly. For example if I use a searching site which is in Spanish or one which is Japanese. Do they not use different criteria? Also, is there a "best day in the week" to travel at? (In where the price is slightly better). I will check how Flightfox works.

Comment: Generally during the week is both cheaper to travel on AND cheaper to book your ticket on. Yes they use different 'criteria' for flights, and that's why an entire forum (flyertalk.com) exists about finding the 'cheap' ones.  A flight from NZ to Aus costs me less if I book it on Air NZ's NZ site instead of their Canadian site.  This is why I like flightfox.com so much - many of their experts know these tricks, and do that hard work for you. Also read [reddit's guide to travel hacking](http://www.reddit.com/r/travel/comments/pkl3z/can_we_get_a_few_links_into_the_sidebar/) for some great 'hacks'.

Comment: Oh yeah this seems pretty complicated, I guess my best bet is to use that site. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah if it was simple to find the cheapest flights, I guess we wouldn't have travel agents :/  I'm almost tempted to join a travel agency for a few months just to learn all the routing codes, haha